# Select com LEFT JOIN e LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Olá, criei um campo de busca, e preciso retornar os resultados da **tb_ordens** com base no nome do cliente. Porém nessa tabela está salvo apenas o id do cliente, e a busca é feita pelo nome. Os dados do cliente estão na **tb_clientes**. Busquei algumas informações nos fóruns, mas não consegui resolver.

```
$get_ordens = $pdo->prepare('SELECT a.*, b.nome FROM tb_ordens as a LEFT JOIN tb_clientes as b on a.cliente = b.nome WHERE fechada = 0 AND (cliente LIKE :busca) ORDER BY data');

$get_ordens->execute(array(
     ':busca' => '%'.$busca.'%'
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que você esteja comparando o id do cliente da tabela ordem com o nome do cliente da tabela cliente.
você precisa fazer o JOIN ligando as devidas relações das tabelas e no WHERE, você faz o filtro pelo nome do cliente que está salvo na tabela cliente.

fiz algumas edições supondo que seja assim a estrutura do seu banco de dados:

```
$sql = '
SELECT o.*, c.nome FROM tb_ordens as o 
LEFT JOIN tb_clientes as c on o.cliente = c.id 
WHERE o.fechada = 0 AND (c.nome LIKE :busca) 
ORDER BY o.data';

$get_ordens = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: Legal, funcionou. Valeu, André!

Answer (score 0):

A solução que o André Walter passou acho que é a mais ideal.
Se quiser fazer um excelente curso de SQL deixo abaixo o link do meu portal de cursos
[www.fpw.com.br/ead](http://www.fpw.com.br/ead)
Lá têm o curso SQL mais completo que você encontra na internet